# Moving every other row to a new column and group pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have an example data set that's much smaller than my actual data set, it is actually a text file and I want to read it in as a pandas table and do something with it:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {
     'one': ['title1', 'R2G', 'title2', 'K5G', 'title2','R14G', 'title2','R2T','title3', 'K10C', 'title4', 'W7C', 'title4', 'R2G', 'title5', 'K8C']
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Example dataset looks like this:

```
df

Out[20]:  
      one
0   title1
1      R2G
2   title2
3      K5G
4   title2
5     R14G
6   title2
7      R2T
8   title3
9     K10C
10  title4
11     W7C
12  title4
13     R2G
14  title5
15     K8C
```

I added a second column called 'value':

```
df.insert(1,'value','')
df

Out[22]: 
      one      value
0   title1
1      R2G
2   title2
3      K5G
4   title2
5     R14G
6   title2
7      R2T
8   title3
9     K10C
10  title4
11     W7C
12  title4
13     R2G
14  title5
15     K8C
```

I want to **first** move every other row over to the 'value' column:

```
      one    value
0   title1    R2G          
1   title2    K5G  
2   title2    R14G 
3   title2    R2T    
4   title3    K10C          
5   title4    W7C            
6   title4    R2G           
7   title5    K8C
```

I **then** want to group by the title name, since there might be more than 1 values for the same title:

```
     one     value
0   title1    R2G          
1   title2    K5G, R14G, R2T   
2   title3    K10C          
3   title4    W7C , R2G                        
4   title5    K8C
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Construct a new df by slicing the column using `iloc` and a step arg:

```
In [185]:
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'one':df['one'].iloc[::2].values, 'value':df['one'].iloc[1::2].values})
new_df

Out[185]:
      one value
0  title1   R2G
1  title2   K5G
2  title2  R14G
3  title2   R2T
4  title3  K10C
5  title4   W7C
6  title4   R2G
7  title5   K8C
```

You can then `groupby` on 'one' and apply a `lambda` on the 'value' column and just `join` the values:

```
In [188]:
new_df.groupby('one')['value'].apply(','.join).reset_index()

Out[188]:
      one         value
0  title1           R2G
1  title2  K5G,R14G,R2T
2  title3          K10C
3  title4       W7C,R2G
4  title5           K8C
```

Comment: What if we have an odd number of values in the one column?

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you can reshape and aggregate by passing groups of values into list.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {
     'one': ['title1', 'R2G', 'title2', 'K5G', 'title2','R14G', 'title2','R2T','title3', 'K10C', 'title4', 'W7C', 'title4', 'R2G', 'title5', 'K8C']
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
# because you have simple alternating pattern, you can just reshape
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, 2), columns = ['one', 'value'])
# groupby on value and aggregate by joining a string
df = df.groupby('one')['value'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right on the output, just recall this form being useful. Not sure what the protocol is in such cases)

Comment: You can update your last line to `.apply(','.join).reset_index()` I personally like the `reshape` method as it's neater so it's worth keeping +1

Comment: @Yakym Pirozhenko Can  you explain what the -1 and 2 mean from the reshape statement?

Comment: Reshape takes an n-tuple (a regular tuple in this case); each position holds an integer with the 'size' of that particular dimension. So `reshsape(_, 2)` will result in something with 2 columns. `-1` is just a shorthand for omitting the explicit size; numpy knows the old shape and the new number of columns, so there is at most one choice for the new number of rows. Hence you do not need to provide it.